# BNHA Fanfic - Momo smears lipstick on her face and pretends to be Shouto to troll Endeavor

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, my-hero-academia

I read the most hilarious Boku no Hero Academia fanfic about a year or so ago, about the class finding out how horrible Endeavor is and they make it their mission to make his life miserable.

There's been tons of fanfics about this subject, but there's one scene that particularly sticks out in my mind and I can't find it which fanfic it was from.

The story was on archive of our own and had a few chapters comprising of  snippets of different scenarios. In one chapter it's time for hero internships and instead of Shouto going to his father's agency, they send Momo instead who pretends to be Shouto...but in a super obvious and hilarious way.

She smears red makeup (I think it was lipstick) over half of her face to mimic his scar and wears a mop or some sort of stringy wig on her head, dyed to be his colors. Then to represent Shouto's fire and ice abilities, I believe she holds ice in one hand and a lighter in the other.

She goes on in a deadpan way the whole time, reaffirming that she is Shouto and eventually his agency goes along with it, lot's of laughter gets aimed at Endeavor. She ends up doing this for the whole week.

I'd like to find this and re-read it so I can die laughing again.

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: I think this is the first non-*Harry Potter* fanfic ID question I've seen here. Never mind the fact that the fanfic actually sounds good...

Comment: @F1Krazy It is, it's a pretty funny crack fic. In another chapter, they make Endeavor a curse word. For example: "Tsuyu is the first one to say it. Bakugou’s gone on some rant again, and Tsuyu just hops up and says, “That’s pretty Endeavor of you.” Bakugou sputters. “What the—what the fuck? I am nothing like that asshole!” and it all spirals from there. You should check it out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! [*More Like ENDEVIL, Amiright?*](https://archiveofourown.org/works/7655554/chapters/17431333) by [TheBabbleRabble](https://archiveofourown.org/users/TheBabbleRabble/pseuds/TheBabbleRabble) (on AO3)

> Kirishima puts his pencil down, turns to face Todoroki, and says as casual as a spring afternoon, “Bro, I really want to punch your dad.”
>
> Or: Four times Todoroki’s classmates ruin Endeavor’s life and career, and one time they don’t have to do anything.

...Yaoyorozu's bit is in Chapter Two. And you're right, it's hilarious.

Comment: YESSSS THIS IS IT. THANK YOU!!!